# TypeScript Playwright: Saving Storagestate via Sign in via API request and then using inside BowserContext does not work - takes me back to login page

Tags: authentication, playwright, playwright-test

I need to decide whether to go with Playwright as an E2E Automation tool or not.

The following piece of code using backend API for sign in is working fine.

But when I use the saved Storagestate file inside the BrowserContext, then it fails to sign me in, hence taking me back to the Login page.

```
test.describe('User login', async () => {

    var browser: any;
  
    test.beforeEach(async () => {
        browser = await chromium.launch({
            channel: 'chrome',
            headless: false
        });
    });

    const requestContext = await request.newContext();
    const response = await requestContext.post(`${testConfig.envConfig.apiURL}/login/authorize`, {
        form: {
            'email': 'user.tech+admin@xxxx.com',
            'password': 'xxxxxx'
        }
    });
    const responseJson = await response.json();
    console.log(responseJson);
    expect(response.ok()).toBeTruthy();
    
    // Save signed-in state.
    await requestContext.storageState({ path: './.storagestates/adminUserStorageState.json' });
    await requestContext.dispose();

    // Using the Storagesate in the BrowserContext
    // page should sign in as a admin user.
        test.use({ storageState: './.storagestates/adminUserStorageState.json' });
        test('Version 1: Cookies stored via Auth. by backend API', async ({ page }) => {
            let url = `/brand/f99f06fb1f121234aaf/gallery`;
            await page.goto(url, {timeout: 60000});
        });
    

        test('Version 2: Cookies stored via Auth. by backend API', async () => {
            // page should sign in as a buyer user.
            const userContext = await browser.newContext({ storageState: './.storagestates/buyerUserStorageState.json' });
            const page = await userContext.newPage();
            await page.goto(`/`, {timeout: 60000});
        });
});
```

Comment: Do you have any stored data inside the "./.storagestates/adminUserStorageState.json" ?
Also i see two tests, which one redirects you to the login page?